# average of an array of data vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, average

I'm new in this stuff of programming. I'have been searching for this topic and I can't find anything that fits to my problem.

I have an array of data with measures. I have 31 lines and 96 columns. I want that my VBA code finds the average of each column of data and displays it on the line after the last value of the column.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer I've found is to use the following:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataArray)`

This is (hypothetically) the same as using the average function in a worksheet. The only downside seems to be that you have to use an array or some other list of data points. This is easily remedied with the following:

```
Function getArray(dataRange As Range) As Variant()
    Dim arr(dataRange.Rows.Count, dataRange.Columns.Count) as Variant
    Dim i as Integer, j as Integer

    For i = 1 to dataRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 to dataRange.Columns.Count
            arr(i, j) = dataRange(i, j)
        Next
    Next

    getArray = arr
End Function
```

This will convert the range into an array and will be accessible through the `Average` function. For instance:

`myAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(getArray(Range("C1:CT56")))`

Comment: The first part of your answer is spot on. The second is really terrible. You get the array like so: `arr = [C1:CT56].Value2`

Answer (score 1):

You can enter a formula in the line below the data:

```
=average(A1:A96)
```

Isn't that easier than using VBA for this purpose?

If you really want to use VBA:

```
Sub ownaverage()
  Dim totalsum As Double
  Dim totalnum As Double
  Dim ownav As Double
  totalsum = 0
  totalnum = 0
  For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D17:E17").Cells
    totalsum = totalsum + c.Value
    totalnum = totalnum + 1
  Next
  ownav = totalsum / totalnum
  ownaverage = ownav
  Range("I27").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ownaverage()
End Sub
```

Reference for loops: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: No, because I already have some code that make some charts, and the final purpose is to create a chart with the average numbers that I get. So I really need the VBA code. My problem is to create a loop in which I can calculate all average of the 96 columns.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer. I have checked again your code and adapted to mine. But I get and over flow error "6". The only change I made was the range to .Range("C28:CT59").Cells as I have 31 lines and 96 columns. Also I don't get it in the code where does the cell with average goes.

Comment: changed my code for larger range and writing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the answer. I was able to figure it out by myself. The code I wrote is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()  
    Dim soma as Double  
    Dim media as Double  
    soma=0  
    media=0  
    totalnum=0  
    With Sheets("sheet1")  
       For j= 1 to 96  
           For i =28 to 58  
              Set target = Cells (i,j)  
              soma=soma+targe  
              totalnum=totalnum+1  
           Next i  
           Cells(i+1,j).Value = soma/totalnum  
           soma=0  
           totalnum=0  
       Next j  
    End With
End sub
```

I hope this code help someone with the same doubts as I had.

Thanks again DaveG