# Find the average of values in an array (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

How do I find the average of the values held in a 2D array in excel VBA?  I have an array named "Numbers" which has values of 1,2,3,4,6  How do I enter the average value into a value named NumbersAve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [average of an array of data vba excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926902/average-of-an-array-of-data-vba-excel)

Comment: `=SUM(elements in array)/COUNT(elements in array)`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs the question you referenced has not accepted answer.

Comment: > 50% of my answers don't get accepted, but I usually get a comment "Thanks it worked for me". Accepting answers just isn't the top of most askers' priorities evidently. But those methods work in that question, and they do have upvoted answers.

Comment: Oops... Many of the times, I have received the same comment from highly reputed users of the site so I thought that we cannot point to unaccepted answers. :( I'm learning.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(numbers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application.Average is sufficient.

```
Dim numbers As Variant, NumbersAve As Double

'by rows
Range("A1") = 1
Range("A2") = 2
Range("A3") = 3
Range("A4") = 4
Range("A5") = 6

numbers = Range("A1:A5").Value2
Debug.Print LBound(numbers, 1) & " to " & UBound(numbers, 1) & ", " & _
            LBound(numbers, 2) & " to " & UBound(numbers, 2)  '<~~ 1 to 5, 1 to 1

NumbersAve = Application.Average(numbers)
Debug.Print NumbersAve                   '<~~ 3.2

'by columns
Range("A1") = 1
Range("B1") = 2
Range("C1") = 3
Range("D1") = 4
Range("E1") = 6

numbers = Range("A1:E1").Value2
Debug.Print LBound(numbers, 1) & " to " & UBound(numbers, 1) & ", " & _
            LBound(numbers, 2) & " to " & UBound(numbers, 2)  '<~~ 1 to 1, 1 to 5

NumbersAve = Application.Average(numbers)
Debug.Print NumbersAve                   '<~~ 3.2
```